# Endpoint Not Found; WCF Facility, Castle Windsor 3.0, WCF 4

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, castle-windsor

After studying the multitude of Castle Windsor posts on configuring the WCF Facility, I have written the following configuration.

This will be hosted in IIS.

The assumptions I have made are:

1) I require the ".Hosted()" extension as I am hosting this in IIS and the "base address" will be resolved by the web server. In other applicaitons I have used the ".AddBaseAddress("http://etc")" when self hosting (Windows service or console app etc), but my understanding is this is not required in this case.

2) The component must be ".Named(...)" in line with the "Service" value of the .svc markup.

3) The ".At(...)" will be registered in addition to the web server address, and therefore does not require the "http://localhost:9278/" prefix.

Setup is as follows:

A central installer from the global.asax file.

```
    public static IWindsorContainer CreateContainer()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>()
        .Install(FromAssembly.This());

        return container;
    }
```

A specific Installer class for the WCF services.

```
    private const string FileServiceAddress = "Services/FileService.svc";

    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container
            .Register(Component.For<IFileService>()
                 .ImplementedBy<FileService>()
                 .Named("FileService")
                 .AsWcfService(new DataServiceModel()
                       .Hosted()
                       .PublishMetadata(o => o.EnableHttpGet())
                       .AddEndpoints(
                           WcfEndpoint
                               .BoundTo(new BasicHttpBinding())
                               .At(FileServiceAddress))));
}
```

And the .svc markup

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
    Language="C#" 
    Debug="true" 
    Service="FileService" 
    CodeBehind="FileService.svc.cs"
    Factory="Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.DefaultServiceHostFactory, 
    Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration" %>
```

However It will not resolve the endpoint when I attempt to debug/run this solution. If i take out the .Hosted() and replace with a .AddBaseAddress(...) for each service I install then it appears to work correctly?! But surely this is wrong behaviour? and duplication of a base address? Surely, this wont register correctly when I deploy it in IIS which handles binding of the base address and port?

[image]
[image]

What am i missing? What is the correct way to register WCF services against the facility?

Help greatly appreciated!

**Update**: After tweaking this works, but why? I am not specifying ANY configuration yet the endpoint is available?

```
        container
            .Register(Component.For<IFileService>()
                          .ImplementedBy<FileService>()
                          .Named("FileService")
                          .LifeStyle.PerWcfOperation());
```